# Difference between CREATE TABLE and CREATE ANY TABLE privileges

Tags: oracle, create-table, privileges, any

I don't understand the difference between these two privileges.

I found these two explanations but it's not helping me.

```
CREATE TABLE -> Enables a user to create a table owned by that user.

CREATE ANY TABLE -> Enables a user to create a table owned by any user in the database.
```

If a user creates a table it's going to be owned by the user that created it right? I don't get it.

Comment: No, not right. The language seems pretty clear. If a user has the CREATE **ANY** TABLE privilege, they can create tables in schemas other than his/her own; that is, those tables will be owned by other users, not by him/her self. What is it that you don't get?

Comment: @mathguy I see. Now I got it.

Comment: If I grant that privilege to `mathguy`, then `mathguy` can create a table in the `scott` schema (owned by `scott`, then!) with something like `create table scott.tbl (id number , .....)`.  Notice that the schema name is prepended to the new table name. This will create a table `TBL` in schema `SCOTT` even though user `scott` didn't create the table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE` privilege lets you create a table in your own schema. So user `scott` can do:

```
create table scott.mytable ( id number );
```

The `CREATE ANY TABLE` privilege lets you create a table in any schema in the database. So again, user `scott` can do:

```
create table hr.employees ( id number );
```

That is, make a table that belongs to someone else.

Comment: Is 'CREATE TABLE' a default privilege that every user automatically gets unless revoked by the DBA?

Comment: I believe there are no default privileges. When you create a user, they can't do anything, not even connect to the database. You must grant the privileges they will need.