# how to create table dynamically through procedure from another schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

I have a requirement to create the tables dynamically through procedure from another schema.
here are the details..

```
user1 -- table T1_YYYMM where YYYYMM= year,month e.g T1_201912 needs to be created on this schema.
user2 -- procedure X to create T1_YYYYMM is created on this schema.
user3 -- want to access the procedure X from user3 which should create the tables on user1.
```

user3 has been given execute permission on p1 but still i am getting permission denied.I dont have access to user1 and user2.All I can access through user3 only. I should not be able to create any table other than T1_YYYYMM on user1.

please advise on this.

from user2 i am able to execute p1 but when I am trying this from user3 i am  getting the insufficient privelege error.

```
grant create any table to user2 -- done 

create or replace PROCEDURE USER2.x (owner_name in varchar2 , 
                                 table_name in varchar2 
                                     ) authid current_user
is
  sql_string VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_owner varchar2(30) := 'USER1';
  l_tab varchar2(100)  := 'T1'; 
  l_month varchar2(30) := to_char(add_months(sysdate),'YYYYMM');
BEGIN
IF  l_owner=owner_name AND l_tab = table_name then
  sql_string := 'CREATE TABLE '||l_owner||'.'||l_tab||'_'||l_month||' AS SELECT * FROM USER1.T2 WHERE 1=2';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_string;
   dbms_output.put_line('Table created :'||l_tab||'_'||l_month);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON '||l_tab||'_'||l_month||' TO V_ROLE  ';
ELSE 
  dbms_output.put_line('Permission Denied...');
END IF;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS  THEN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
END X;
/


grant execute on x to USER3 ;--DONE

/

EXEC USER3.X('USER1','T1');

ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Are you sure that procedure P1 is executing without errors from user2(owner of the procedure) ?

Comment: @Tejash yes I am able to execute P1 from user2 and table is created on user1.

Answer (score 0):

You *missing link* is the privilege

```
 grant create any table to user2;
```

without it you observe

```
 ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

**Full Setup**

1) grant `create any table` to `user2` -- done by DBA

2) create procedure in `user2`

```
create procedure x as
begin
  execute immediate 'create table user1.tab1 (x number)';
end;
/
```

3) grant `execute`on `x` to `USER3`

```
 grant execute on x to USER3;
```

4) `USER3` runs the procedure

```
begin 
  user2.x;
end;
/
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495638/4808122) - simple `CREATE TABLE` privilege is not sufficient to create tables in other schemas.

Also note, that this privilege must be given *direct* to the user (i.e. *not via a role*) to be able to be used in a procedure.

**Alternatives**

As pointed out in a comment, a more secure alternative is to *move the procedure from user2 to user1*, i.e. the procedure and the table to be created would be in the same schema.

In that case only `execute` privilege on the procedure must be granted to `USER3`.

Comment: Granting CREATE ANY may be a security hole. Answer should, in my opinion, contain comment to reconsider alternatives (ex: create in another user schema and provide grants to original user). 
Also, when talking about grants, roles and procedures, it might be useful to mention invoker rights clause (possibility to use current user grants).

Comment: @igr considered the *security hint*; the *invoker rights* are important, but not relevant in this scenario.